# CSS: How to make an input text border to cover the text around it?

Tags: css, text, static

I would like to blend a static value next to a simple text input form.
so it will look like, for example:
[static]What do you think about[/static] [user info]...[/userinfo].
i've came up with this:

```
        <p style="display:inline;">What Is It Like To Be</p>

        <div>
            <input name="post_title" type="text" id="topic"  class="input" size="50" maxlength="100" tabindex="1" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET["pr"];?>" style="padding-left:45px; " style="display:inline;"/>
        </div>
```

So, I do get the static 'prefix' inlined with the input form, but i want to make the static text look 'like' it is part of the form. Like a static 'placeholder' tag.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Can we do with jQuery? [text]

Comment: I'm unclear on whether you're trying to show the static text on the same line as the text field, *inside* the text field, or something else. The former can be done in [a few different ways](http://jsfiddle.net/avxFE/1/).

Comment: ^ that, so I will revise my answer if i'm off base :P

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<label class="input-stretch">prefix_<input type="text" /></label>​
```

**CSS**

```
.input-stretch {
 border: 1px solid #222;
 padding: 0.1em;    
}
.input-stretch input {
 border: none;
 outline: none !important;    
}
​
```

Basically remove the input border and outline, then add one to the label or whatever other element you want to wrap it in.

`outline: none !important;` may also need to be applied on active/focus states, iirc chrome gives it some nice blue outline??

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ypZu8/1/)

Comment: in the meantime i found another way to solve it, which goes like this:
creating a container div with "position:relative". create 2 sub div with "position:relative". playing with: margins, top and left.
however - your suggestion looks much more elegant and i'll try it as I have time. Thanks for your willing to help :)